# Inexplicable ValueError in Pycharm with Python 3.10.4

Tags: python, pycharm

First and foremost: I'm using **Ubuntu 22.04** and **Python 3.10.4**.

Suddenly my PyCharm IDE is showing me a inexplicable `ValueError` when I run the script.

A code as simple as bellow return a value error on line 2

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
print(f'{a + b}')
```

My input:

```
1
1
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/sample/Python/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    b = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Funny enough, if I type anything inside the `input()` function at line 2, the code works:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input("Second number: "))
print(f'{a + b}')
```

Result:

```
1
Second number: 1
2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Video of the actual behavior:

[image: behavior]

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: How exactly are you providing the input?

Comment: @chepner . . . Typing in the keyboard, as usual. . .

Comment: The error suggests you are hitting Enter without actually typing anything. The argument to `input` won't change that, although it might make it more obvious when you are *supposed* to type something.

Comment: @chepner. . . I've added a video of the behavior to the question. . .

Comment: There seems to be no end to the number of ridiculous quirks in PyCharm....

Comment: Are you on Windows? My guess is Python and PyCharm are both being clever by trying to convert line endings automatically and it ends up sending an extra newline. Writing a prompt with input clears the buffer so it  doesn't happen in that case.

Comment: @chepner. . . xD I'm mad at this right now. . .

Comment: @Evan I'm using Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Granted, my sole impression of PyCharm comes from the never-ending stream of questions like this on Stack Overflow, but I would recommend just not using it. There's nothing wrong with your *code*.

Comment: I tested your code on Ubuntu 22.04 without PyCharm (write script in vim, save to file, run from gnome terminal), as expected - I can not reproduce the issue. I believe this is a bug in the implementation of PyCharm terminal emulator. By forcing it to print a prompt and thus switch between `stdin` and `stdout` something must get reset, and that is how your workaround works. I generally don't like MS stuff, but I would recommend VS code for Ubuntu to work with Python. (Better yet VS Codium - the non MS spyware version)

Comment: @LevM. . . .same here `python3 main.py` worked out perfectly. Not sure what's going on with Pycharm. Anyways, I'm gonna follow your suggestion and start using Codium. . .

Comment: I think this is bug in Pycharm, see [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54238/STDIN-is-lost-for-a-second-input-call](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54238/STDIN-is-lost-for-a-second-input-call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tldr update to 2022.1.2 where [PyCharm bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54238/STDIN-is-lost-for-a-second-input-call) was fixed.